# Newly added IP addresses not selectable for IIS bindings

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-6

A colleague of mine added several IP addresses to a server, but these IPs are not appearing in the list to use with bindings.

This goes for IIS7 web sites and IIS6 FTP sites.

We found this KB article, but I don't have the offending patch installed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2551090/en-us

I don't think the server was restarted after the IPs were added as it is a live production server, but I believe IIS (at least from IIS6) was restarted.

What must we do to be able to use these IPs? They are pingable.

**UPDATE 1:**
I am able to RDP to the new IP addresses without issues.

**UPDATE 2:**
I was able to make them appear by adding them to the `hosts` file, but I'd still like to know what the issue is?

Comment: Restarting IIS from the IIS6 console will only affect SMTP Virtual Servers. It won't touch any web-related services. Have you tried restarting IIS from the IIS 7 console?

Comment: Does that count for the FTP side of things also? I can't be sure what my colleague did, but likely not. They are there now that I have added them to hosts file, so I can't restart and see if this changes things without removing them first (something I doubt they'd be keen on). Thanks for that info though :)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/551218/92108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server needed a reboot (or at least the correct services started).

We added them to the hosts file to force them to appear, but a reboot makes them appear without being in hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

Let's come back to old time though this is old post. I recently came a cross this issue and I open services.msc, and then restart IP Helper, and all IP newly added comes up.

Comment: I can't test this, but thanks for replying. If it occurs again I'll try this.